# Pandas: Filtering timeseries data from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, time-series

I am trying to write a program which involves monitoring the electric power consumption in watts for a house. I have two sets of dataframes. The first one (`df_appliances`) contains multiple columns of appliances with their wattage recorded after every 10 mins like so:

```
Timestamp       Dishwasher  TV    Desktop_PC    Washer/Dryer    AC_unit     Fridge
10/28/2022 9:00     0       60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 9:10     0       60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 9:20     0       60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 9:30     0       0     0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 9:40     1800    0     0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 9:50     1800    0     0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:00    1800    0     0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:10    1800    60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:20    1800    60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:30    1800    60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:40    0       0     0             0               0         250
10/28/2022 10:50    0       0     0             0               0         250
10/28/2022 11:00    0       0     300           0               0         250
10/28/2022 11:10    0       0     300           0               0         250
10/28/2022 11:20    0       0     300           0               0         250
10/28/2022 11:30    0       60    300           0               0         250
10/28/2022 11:40    0       60    300           0               0         250
10/28/2022 11:50    0       60    300           0               2500        250
10/28/2022 12:00    0       60    300           3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:10    0       60    300           3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:20    0       0     300           3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:30    0       0     0             3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:40    0       0     0             3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:50    0       0     0             3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 13:00    0       0     0             3000            2500        250
```

Similarly I have another dataframe (`df_total`) from a different source which contains the sum of the total wattage like so:

```
DATETIME            Total_Watts
10/28/2022 9:00     2810
10/28/2022 9:10     2810
10/28/2022 9:20     2810
10/28/2022 9:30     2750
10/28/2022 9:40     4550
10/28/2022 9:50     4550
10/28/2022 10:00    4550
10/28/2022 10:10    4610
10/28/2022 10:20    4610
10/28/2022 10:30    4610
10/28/2022 10:40    250
10/28/2022 10:50    250
10/28/2022 11:00    550
10/28/2022 11:10    550
10/28/2022 11:20    550
10/28/2022 11:30    610
10/28/2022 11:40    610
10/28/2022 11:50    3110
10/28/2022 12:00    6110
10/28/2022 12:10    6110
10/28/2022 12:20    6050
10/28/2022 12:30    5750
10/28/2022 12:40    5750
10/28/2022 12:50    5750
10/28/2022 13:00    5750
```

current tasks:

1. Create a new dataframe (`df_output`) which is a filtered version of df_appliances where the **4000** watt threshold in df_total is crossed
2. Introduce a time-based filter where the program records data *20 mins* before the threshold start time.

I was able to accomplish the first task through the following lines of code (I would also appreciate a more elegant solution in the form of a function):

```py
start_time = df_total['DATETIME'][df_total['Total_Watts'] >= 4000].tolist()
df_output = df_appliances[df_appliances['Timestamp'].isin(start_time)]
```

Essentially my output should look something like this:

```
Timestamp       Dishwasher  TV    Desktop_PC    Washer/Dryer    AC_unit     Fridge
10/28/2022 9:20     0       60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 9:30     0       0     0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 9:40     1800    0     0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 9:50     1800    0     0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:00    1800    0     0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:10    1800    60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:20    1800    60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 10:30    1800    60    0             0               2500        250
10/28/2022 11:40    0       60    300           0               0         250
10/28/2022 11:50    0       60    300           0               2500        250
10/28/2022 12:00    0       60    300           3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:10    0       60    300           3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:20    0       0     300           3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:30    0       0     0             3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:40    0       0     0             3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 12:50    0       0     0             3000            2500        250
10/28/2022 13:00    0       0     0             3000            2500        250
```

Comment: Please copy paste your data instead of posting an image

Comment: @bitflip Sorry for that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to merge and then filter based on your criterium.

```
df = df_appliances.merge(df_total, left_on="Timestamp", right_on="DATETIME")

print(df[(df.Total_Watts >= 4000) | (df.Total_Watts.shift(-1) >= 4000) | (df.Total_Watts.shift(-2) >= 4000)])
```

Edit:

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
start_times = df[df.Total_Watts >= 4000].Timestamp.to_list()
df[df.apply(lambda row: any(val in pd.Interval(row.Timestamp - pd.Timedelta(microseconds=1), 
                                               row.Timestamp + pd.Timedelta(minutes=20)) for val in start_times), axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Any other way to describe the shift functions in terms of the timestamp value that is 20 mins before the start time? Some of the data has values where the data intervals are less or more than 10 mins

Comment: Only one using apply. I've added it, but maybe someone else has a better idea.